# Hauppauge winTv SoloHD unclaimed

Tags: drivers, usb, dvb

I'm trying to use Hauppauge's winTv soloHd USB stick on ubuntu 16.04 and 15.10, both seem to detect the stick, but `kaffeine` as well as `me-tv` both say there's no dvb device attached to the computer; I get UNCLAIMED when running `lshw` (translated):

```
*-usb:1 UNCLAIMED
               Description: Common USB-Device
               Product: soloHD
               Manufacturer: HCW
               Physical ID: 2
               Bus-Informationen: usb@3:2
               Version: 1.00
               Seriennummer(ID): 0011512436
               Capabilities: usb-2.00
               Configuration: maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
```

`lsusb` gives this output:

```
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 2040:0264 Hauppauge
```

Running `dmesg` outputs the following for the device

```
[  297.462255] usb 3-2: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[  297.591028] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=2040, idProduct=0264
[  297.591032] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=1, SerialNumber=2
[  297.591035] usb 3-2: Product: soloHD
[  297.591037] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: HCW
[  297.591039] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: 0011512436
```

The kernel I'm using on the 16.04 machine is `4.4.0-21-generic`.

According to [linuxtv](https://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Hauppauge_WinTV-soloHD) the card should work fine on linux since 2015-11-19.

Is there anything I can do to make those programs detect the stick?

---

Comment: Also [this](http://www.hauppauge.co.uk/site/products/data_solohd.html) claims Linux support for the WinTV-soloHD is in kernel 3.16, but is that incorrect?

Comment: I couldn't get it to work with that @jarno

Comment: Does it work with some later mainline kernel then? (See [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved it.

First, install the dependencies, then build and make v4l-dvb as described [here](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/v4l-dvb/). After doing this, the stick was detected and the "unclaimed" disappeared. However, I still didn't get a signal.

To get it, the following drivers are needed in order to make it work:

[dvb-demod-si2168-02.fw](https://github.com/OpenELEC/dvb-firmware/blob/master/firmware/dvb-demod-si2168-02.fw) and [dvb-demod-si2168-b40-01.fw](https://github.com/OpenELEC/dvb-firmware/blob/master/firmware/dvb-demod-si2168-b40-01.fw)

I've downloaded and copied them to /lib/firmware, rebooted and now everything works fine.

Comment: Do you have to build and make v4l-dvb after each kernel update?

Comment: Yes it seems so @jarno

Comment: Could you try with Ubuntu's linux kernel version 4.4.0-22 or later, if you could do without building v4l-dvb?

Answer (score 0):

You need only the dvb-demod-si2168-b40-01.fw file in /lib/firmware. The stick works with newer kernels. Kernel 4.4.52 (see kernel.org) has no entry in the sourcefile /drivers/media/dvb-core/dvb-usb-ids.h for the stick, so the stick is not recognised and the driver did not load. Kernel 4.9.13 and higher (see kernel.org) has the entry and the modules (drivers) will be loaded.I know some Linux distros with kernel earlier than 4.9.13 that work. (Netrunner 17.01 has kernel 4.8.0 and MX-16)